# How to redirect on a click event, but NOT a touch event in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-popper

Complete newbie here, be gentle.

I'm using react-popper and react router-dom.

I have a top navigation component where, if you hover over a Menu item, sub navigation items appear (which are links). I would like, in the event of a click event, to be able to click on the main menu item and redirect the user. However for a touch event I'd want them to just be able to expand the sub navigation options, and not immediately redirect.

How would I go about this? do I just need to create a handleClickEvent which redirects?

Comment: What do you mean by a touch event?

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to structure your HTML properly to handle this.  I would wrap your link in a div and implement what looks like a SyntheticEvent in React.  The idea here is you want one event to trigger on click and another on touch, which means you'll want to stopPropagation.  https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html. Not very familiar with React but I think if you follow this path you'll find an answer.

Comment: @RobertAndrei by touch event I mean tapping on a touch screen such as a phone or ipad. Since there is no hover state for them, I wouldn't want to immediately redirect them to another page without being able to expand the sub navigation popper

Comment: @DylanWright Ah, this looks like what I need, thank you! I will check it out